# Is undermethylation considered a legitimate diagnosis?

Tags: blood-tests, epigenetic

Apparently undermethylation can be diagnosed using blood work. I googled it a bit, and what I saw seemed to suggest that it isn't widely accepted in the medical community.

I'm wondering how legitimate this diagnosis is. That's hard to define, but I suppose that would mean "has been discussed in peer-reviewed articles in legitimate journals," among other things.

Also, to clarify: I don't doubt that it's a *thing*. I guess to put my question even more precisely, it would be "is it considered legitimate to care about it and attach weight to it."

Comment: The terms you're looking for might be "of clinical significance" "strength of evidence" and "evidence-based."  I had to google it because I was surprised to hear the organic chem/epigenetic term used this way.  I am NOT well versed in the strength of data about alternative medicine, so I will leave the answer to someone else.  I recommend a couple changes to the Q:  1. Define undermethylation using a strong resource.  2. it's better to ask what data supports it rather than asking if something is legit.  3. show examples of the information you found on it to give a starting point.  Welcome :)

Comment: Health SE in general does not often discuss alternative medicine topics.  Some have large amounts of strong evidence supporting them, others do not, and there are a lot of strong opinions on all sides.  Look at this meta: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95/should-alternative-medicine-be-on-topic

Comment: Well, are we sure that it IS alternative medicine (as opposed to mainstream)? That's part of my question.